# NVM doesn't update Node to the newest version

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nvm

I'm using NVM (Node version manager) version 1.1.7 on Windows 10 to update Node through the Powershell terminal on VSCode. Today it occured to me that even though after updating and using `nvm use 14.15.4` and getting 2 elevation dialogs and NVM telling me that it's now using the newest version, when I do `nvm list` or `node -v` or `get-command node` they're all still telling me that it uses an older version of Node.

After looking around for a bit some solutions said to add `"runtimeExecutable": "/Users/*user*/.nvm/versions/node/*version*/bin/node"` to the `launch.json` of VSCode, but that specific path doesn't even exist on my computer.

Comment: So there's two `nvm`s. There's the normal `nvm` (Mac/Linux) and nvm for Windows. I'm familiar with both and that stuff that you can't find with `/.nvm/versions/node` is definitely only applicable if you're using the Linux/Mac version. I'm also on 1.1.7 on my Windows machine and cannot reproduce your bug. `nvm install latest`, `nvm use 15.5.1`, `node -v` shows 15.5.1, `nvm list` shows *15.5.1. You might need to close and restart your terminal, maybe the whole VS code window.

Comment: I should mention that `nvm` tells me that the newer version is installed, but I cannot switch to it for whatever reason. @JakeAve

Comment: You probably have installed an old version of nodejs. Look in control panel, check your PATH environment.

Comment: It tells me that the path is `AppData\Roaming\npm`. Should I set it to something else? @JeffRSon

Comment: node.exe shouldn't be there. How does the PATH variable look like? What's the output of `where.exe node.exe`? What's the value of NVM_HOME and NVM_SYMLINK?

Comment: @JeffRSon sorry about the late reply. `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` is in the Path variable (PATH isn't all uppercase so I'm not sure if that's important), `where,exe` doesn't seem to exist if i do `get-command where`, but for node it's `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`. NVM_HOME is `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm` and NVM_SYMLINK is `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Comment: The point is, if there's another node.exe to be found prior to `program files\nodejs\node.exe` in PATH. BTW, it's where.exe with a dot! So check if `program files\nodejs` is a symlink to the correct version path inside NVM_HOME, and if that node.exe is the correct version (see details from context menu).

Comment: Well, it doesn't point to any specific version in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm`, there are just folders of the different versions that are installed. The version of node in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` is the older version that I'm suck with. (Also, `where,exe` was a typo. It's `where.exe`.) @JeffRSon

Comment: I would uninstall nvm und nodejs from ControlPanel, remove NVM home folder, remove `program files\nodejs`, then reinstall just nvm,

Comment: Maybe [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036376/vs-code-node-version-is-older-than-node-version-on-my-system/71927104#71927104) could help you

Answer (score 0):

Check if **`nvm alias default <version>`** solves the problem