# how to change to an older/stable version of node in VS-Code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using VS-code and current version of node  is v16.4.0 Now, I wish to change it to 14.17.5 or 14.17.6 , whatever is stable.
Using Ubuntu 18

(& my npm version is 7.18.1)

Comment: You should take a look at nvm ...

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is an editor it has nothing to do with your current node version, maybe there is an extension that does that

If you want to have multiple node versions and switch between them easily you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: no, i don't want to use multiple versions. I just to want to downgrade it to a stable version.  Kindly tell me how to do it.

Comment: If you installed using `apt` just run `apt remove nodejs` and then follow [this](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) guide for installing

Comment: Also nvm give you the possibility to switch versions quickly and easily, if you want only one version on your system you can uninstall the previous version and installing your desired version

Comment: I have used the command sudo apt-get remove nodejs. But it is still showing the version, via node -v command

Comment: how did you installed nodejs?

Comment: months back installed nodejs in ubuntu, don't remember how. Right now it is showing version 16

Comment: Maybe [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036376/vs-code-node-version-is-older-than-node-version-on-my-system/71927104#71927104) could help you